# SignalR .Net Core Multiple Connection

Tags: angular, signalr, core-api

Hello I have application backend is .NET Core and frontend is Angular 2+. I have one page that two people can both chat and see report in charts. I want to connect chart data and chat to backend with signalR. I can connected chat application. But how can I also make connection for chart datas? If there is any idea i will be so happy.

Comment: You want this on same hub, or two different hubs?

Comment: I want it in different hubs. Different url . When i call data in hub I don't want to get both messages and chart infos. They should come in different hub and connections

Comment: Then you just need to your client service connect with the other hub. What is your exactly your problem here?

Comment: For angular part there is no problem . What about core api part. how can I add second link in startup.cs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add another hub, you just create the second hub class and add it on the startup like:

```cs
public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, HostConfiguration hostConfiguration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    base.Configure(app, hostConfiguration, logger);

    app.UseWebSockets();

    app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        routes.MapHub<DataHub>("/dataHub");
    });
}
```